# Change size of Multilookup field

Tags: sharepoint-designer, lookup-column

I have a multi lookup just like this image, with 2 listboxes and Add and Remove buttons:

http://mastykarz.nl/blog/images/ExtendingLookupFieldswithAddnewitemoptio_6981/SingleMultipleLookupFields_thumb.png

The problem is that the buttons are too long. 
I have tried to shorten them with jQuery, but it seems Sharepoint somehow overrides my setting and/or does not allow it.

I'm probably missing something obvious, but is there a way to alter the size of the Add/Remove buttons in such a control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following JavaScript function could be used for customizing control for [SPFieldMultiLookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldlookup.aspx)

```
//Specify width for Add & Remove buttons in SPFieldMultiLookup control
function customizeMultiLookupField()
{ 
    var j = jQuery.noConflict();   
    j('button[id$="_AddButton"]').css('width','72px');
    j('button[id$="_RemoveButton"]').css('width','72px');
}
```

### Usage:

Save specified function in JS file and place it in Layouts folder.

Reference it in NewForm.aspx page and call it:

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("customizeMultiLookupField");
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I really thought there is an obvious solution, like changing some property value in Sharepoint Designer or somewhere. But it seems jQuery is the solution in most cases. Thank you

Comment: Thank you! Your solution works like a charm.
Where do you know the control IDs like '_AddButton' and '_RemoveButton'?
I need to change the size from both Listboxes. Where or how can I find information about the IDs? Best Regards
Patrick.